# Funcion y condicional

Tags: r

Buenas noches.
Tengo dos vectores, uno con datos binarios

`M <- c(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0)`

y otro con datos no binarios
`C <- c(2.5, 3)`

Necesito crear una función (en R) que asigne un valor del vector C, cada vez que se encuentre un valor de 1 del vector M, que reemplace el valor de uno por los valores de C. El ejemplo seria:

```
(2.5, 0, 0, 5.3, 0, 0)
```

Lo ideal seria usar if, solo que no estoy consiguiendo generar ese reemplazo.

Comment: Por favor agrega un __[mcve]__ que muestre qué estás haciendo.

Answer (score 2):

La forma más fácil y rápida es la siguiente:

```
m<-c(1,0,0,1,0,0)
c<-c(2.5,3)
m[m == 1] <- c
m
> 2.5 0.0 0.0 3.0 0.0 0.0
```

Pero tienes que tener en cuenta que los valores de `c` se reciclan, por ejemplo:

```
m<-c(1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,1)
c<-c(2.5,3)

m[m == 1] <- c
m

> 2.5 0.0 0.0 3.0 0.0 0.0 2.5 0.0 3.0
```

Si no quieres reciclar los valores de `c` y solo reemplazar los `n` valores de `c` puedes hacer esto:

```
m<-c(1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,1)
c<-c(2.5,3)
m[which(m == 1)[1:length(c)]]<-c
m

> [1] 2.5 0.0 0.0 3.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 1.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Puede ser así:

```
bin<-c(1,0,0,1,0)
nbin<-c(3.6,4.5)

sustituye_unos<-function(bin,nbin){
     k<-1
     for(i in 1:length(bin)){
          if(bin[i]==1&(!is.na(nbin[k]))){
               bin[i]<-nbin[k]
               k<-k+1
          }else{#¿Que pasa si se terminan los número en nbin?}
     }
     return(bin)
}

> sustituye_unos(bin,nbin)
[1] 3.6 0.0 0.0 4.5 0.0
```